# How long a dog can remember its owner's smell?

Tags: memory, dogs

Can dog remember multiple smells? and how long it can remember a smell?

Comment: There are a lot of misconceptions about dogs memories. They have short attention spans but they do form long term memories. If my partner has been out for the day and they return home several minutes before I return home for a walk with our beagle, he will excitedly alert to their scent. He does not do that otherwise, so he is picking up on the particular chemical signature that they produce.